# Apache index.html content not refreshed!

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a static index.html with css and images. I uploaded a fresh index.html with fixes but the content was not showing - the page/changes were not visible/refreshed. If I look into the source I can see that image paths has been changed into strange long "cache-like" paths.

E.g. from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://mydomain.com/stylesheets/screen.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://mydomain.com/stylesheets/cc.2c251d9cae64435f25c60ee79fc472a4.screen,s+jquery,oprettyPhoto,s?123.css">
```

It is not browser's issue because the response in the console is the same.

How can I fix that?

UPDATE:
I use mod_expires and mod_pagespeed.

Comment: Your server is obviously doing some optimization on assets served which probably includes some aggressive caching on HTML pages. A hard refresh doesn't help?

Comment: nope... what do you mean by hard refresh? I restarted Apache but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

OK... I see now... mod_pagespeed is causing problems. Somehow it does not refresh content.

Comment: Specifically, `mod_pagespeed` will [cache static resources automatically](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html).  Also, please mark this answer as accepted! :)

Comment: I cant accept it :) have to wait for some hours :).